# Proof: $f$ is continuous if and only if the preimage of every open subset $V$ of $Y$ is open.

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

I know there is a very similar question being asked here, but the answers to that question do not answer the question I have here. They use a different proof, and the one below is one my professor gave so I need to understand it.

Anyway, my professor gave us the following theorem and proof and I'm having trouble understanding the last step.

---

*Theorem: $f: X \to Y$ is continuous if and only if $f^{-1}(V)$ is open for every open $V\subset Y$*

*Proof:* 

 Assume $f$ is continuous and $V$ is open - by the definition of openness:

$$\text{For every }f(x)\in V\text{ there exists }\epsilon_x:B(f(x), \epsilon_x) ⊂ V$$

By the definition of continuity:

$$\text{For every }\epsilon_x\text{ there exists }\delta_x: B(x, \delta_x) \subset f^{-1}(B(f(x), \epsilon_x))$$

$$\implies f^{-1}(V) = \bigcup_{f(x)\in V}B(x, \delta_x) $$

Since, $f^{-1}(V)$ is the union of open sets then $f^{-1}(V)$ is open.

---

Okay so, I understand the last sentence (and I omit the proof), but the implication before that sentence? Why is the preimage of $V$ the union of all balls with centre $X$ and radius $\delta_x$ ?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your definition of continuity is wrong. $B(x, \delta_x)$ is an open ball in $X$ while $B(f(x), \epsilon_x)$ is an open ball in $Y$. So unless $X \subseteq Y$, $B(x, \delta_x) \subseteq B(f(x), \epsilon_x)$ makes no sense.

Comment: Whoops my bad I left out a preimage sign! Will edit now! Silly mistake.

Answer (score 1):

$∀x∈f^{-1}(V) ⊂ X$, there is an $\epsilon_x$ defined above, such that
$$ ∃δ_x : f(\Bbb B(x,δ_x) ) ⊂ \Bbb B(f(x),ε_x) ⊂ V$$
So that
$$ \Bbb B(x,δ_x) ⊂ f^{-1}(\Bbb B(f(x),ε_x)) ⊂ f^{-1}(V)$$

Then we have $$f^{-1}(V) = \bigcup_{x∈ f^{-1}(V)}\{x\} ⊆ \bigcup_{x∈ f^{-1}(V)} \Bbb B(x,δ_x) ⊆ \bigcup_{x∈ f^{-1}(V)} f^{-1} (\Bbb B(f(x),ε_x)) ⊆  \bigcup_{x∈ f^{-1}(V)} f^{-1}(V) = f^{-1}(V)  $$

So $f^{-1}(V) = \bigcup_{x∈ f^{-1}(V)} \Bbb B(x,δ_x)$.

---

notes:

- I have a small issue with writing $∀ f(x) ∈ V$ because we don't necessarily have a unique preimage. The arbitrary unions thing helps a little.
- this isn't a complete proof (but of course you knew that)

Comment: Mhmm, I knew it's not complete; going back the other way makes sense to me. Thanks for your answer it really helped.