# Prove a specific piecewise function is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity

> Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function on $\Bbb X \subset \Bbb R$. Let $a, b \in\Bbb 
> R$ and $a < b$. Prove that the following function is also continuous on $\Bbb X$:
>   $$
> f(a, b, x) = \begin{cases}
> f(x),\ \text{if $a \le f(x) \le b$} \\
> a,\ \text{if $f(x) < a$}\\
> b,\ \text{if $f(x) > b$}
> \end{cases}
> $$

Intuitively the function above is defined in a way to "cut" the upper and lower parts of $f(x)$. So my idea was to define a new function in terms of $\min$ and $\max$ functions. I've started by defining a couple of helper functions. Let:
$$
g(x) = \min\{b; f(x)\}\\
h(x) = \max\{a; f(x)\}
$$

[Here is a visualization](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zcpqtf1ny6) in desmos I've been playing with. Using $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ we might redefine $f(x)$ as:
$$
f(x) = \max\left\{\min\{g(x); h(x)\}; a\right\}
$$

Consider min and max functions in the following form:
$$
\begin{align*}
\max\{x, y\} = {1\over 2}(x + y) + {1\over 2}|x-y|\tag1\\
\min\{x, y\} = {1\over 2}(x + y) - {1\over 2}|x-y|\tag2
\end{align*}
$$

Using the above definition it follows that both min and max are continuous in case $x$ and $y$ are continuous by composition of continuous functions. Since $c_1(x) = b$ is a constant function and $c_2(x) = a$ is also a constant function, then they are both continuous. $f(x)$ is also continuous by initial conditions.

Using these facts we obtain: $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ are continuous by composition of continuous functions is continuous.

At this point, I'm not sure whether I need to express $f(x)$ in terms of $(1)$ and $(2)$. I mean we could rewrite $f(x)$ as:
$$
f(x) = {1\over 2}(\min\{g(x); h(x)\} + a) + {1\over 2}|\min\{g(x); h(x)\} - a| = \cdots
$$

And we could continue the same way until we get a huge expression in terms of $(1)$ and $(2)$ without mentioning min and max. So eventually we would again obtain a composition of continuous functions which is also continuous. But that is redundant, isn's that?

I'm interested whether the approach above is even correct? If not, what would be a way to show $f(a,b,x)$ is continuous? Also, could we find a more simple approach?

Thank you!

Comment: I like this approach. I think it is the best one, in fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Remark*: I like the proof as posted, especially the elegant construction of min and max. The following is merely an alternative.)

For clarity define $g(x) \equiv f(a,b,x)$.
[Recall](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1446460/proof-f-is-continuous-if-and-only-if-the-preimage-of-every-open-subset-v-of) that $g(x)$ is continuous if and only if $g^{-1}(S)$ is open whenever $S$ is open. So let $S$ be any open subset of $[a,b]$ (the codomain of $g$). Now $g^{-1}(S) = f^{-1}(S)$ by construction. Moreover $f$ is continuous so $f^{-1}(S)$ is open. Result follows.